# C# - Generate X509 Certificate based on a given issuer certificate in byte[]

Tags: c#, ssl, bouncycastle, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I want to create iothub device certificates from C# code. The root CA is stored in keyvault as a .pfx, fetched as a string, and then converted from base 64 in order to obtain the certificate bytes as it is required for a certificate stored in keyvault: [Azure Key Vault Certificates does not have the Private Key when retrieved via IKeyVaultClient.GetCertificateAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51451902/azure-key-vault-certificates-does-not-have-the-private-key-when-retrieved-via-ik)

I want to write a function that will take these bytes, along with a subject name (for the leaf certificate) and will create a x509 certificate (with both public and private keys) that would have the issuer as the root.

Here is what I have sketched so far:

```cs
public static X509Certificate2 GenerateCertificateBasedOnIssuer(string subjectName, byte[] issuerByteCert)
        {
            var issuerCertificate = new X509Certificate2(issuerByteCert);

            RSA keyProvider = issuerCertificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();

            CertificateRequest certificateRequest = new CertificateRequest($"CN={subjectName}", keyProvider, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

            CryptoApiRandomGenerator randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();
            SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(randomGenerator);
            BigInteger serialNumber = BigIntegers.CreateRandomInRange(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.ValueOf(Int64.MaxValue), random);

            var publicOnlyDeviceCertificate = certificateRequest.Create(issuerCertificate, issuerCertificate.NotBefore, issuerCertificate.NotAfter, serialNumber.ToByteArray());

            return publicOnlyDeviceCertificate; // oh no ! :(

        }
```

The issue I am having with this solution is that the created certificate only contains a public key.

I found another solution that appears to solve my problem on another Stack Overflow question using `BouncyCastle`'s `X509V3CertificateGenerator`:  [Generate a self-signed certificate on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230745/generate-a-self-signed-certificate-on-the-fly)

The issue I have with this solution is that I cannot convert my rootCA certificate's private key to an `AsymmetricKeyParameter` (first parameter of the `X509V3CertificateGenerator.Generate` method). I tried converting the issuer's key to `AsymmetricKeyParameter`  using this solution: [convert PEM encoded RSA public key to AsymmetricKeyParameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44459497/convert-pem-encoded-rsa-public-key-to-asymmetrickeyparameter), but I got an invalid operation exception.

I was wondering if I was on the right path (as far as understanding goes) and if there is a way to generate a certificate with a private (and public key) based on the code I currently have in place.

UPDATE: I have been able to convert a private key to an AsymmetricKeyParameter by hardcoding the key as follows:

```cs
 string testKey = @"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
<THE KEY>
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
";
 var stringReader = new StringReader(testKey);
 var pemReader = new PemReader(stringReader);
 var pemObject = pemReader.ReadObject(); 
 var keyParam = ((AsymmetricKeyParameter)pemObject);
```

Azure keyvault stores certificate in a pfx format. I am thinking of storing the private key as a secret string. I will keep testing with an hardcoded key for now until I get to a working solution.

I am now testing with `BouncyCastle` and will come back with a working solution if it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key you pass to `CertificateRequest` is used as the public key in the cert... so you want to pass a new key, not the issuer's key.

Then, once you now have the subject key, you use CopyWithPrivateKey at the end to glue them back together.

```
public static X509Certificate2 GenerateCertificateBasedOnIssuer(string subjectName, byte[] issuerByteCert)
{
    using (var issuerCertificate = new X509Certificate2(issuerByteCert))
    using (RSA subjectKey = RSA.Create(2048))
    {
        CertificateRequest certificateRequest = new CertificateRequest($"CN={subjectName}", subjectKey, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

        CryptoApiRandomGenerator randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(randomGenerator);
        BigInteger serialNumber = BigIntegers.CreateRandomInRange(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.ValueOf(Int64.MaxValue), random);

        var publicOnlyDeviceCertificate = certificateRequest.Create(issuerCertificate, issuerCertificate.NotBefore, issuerCertificate.NotAfter, serialNumber.ToByteArray());

        using (publicOnlyDeviceCertificate)
        {
            return publicOnlyDeviceCertificate.CopyWithPrivateKey(subjectKey);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It actually works very well, thanks! However, it seems like the leaf certificate has the same private key as the root certificate. Is there a way to have a completely different set of keys? Thanks!

Comment: @vitonimal If you used the code as shown (making a new key, not getting a reference to the issuer’s key) then they keys will be different… unless you won the random number generator lottery and produced the same RSA key twice.

Comment: You are right! Looks like I just did not see correctly! Thanks a lot! That was the best and most straight forward answer on that subject that I have seen for the past few days!